# RavenDB index for 2 nested many-to-many relationship entities

Tags: c#, linq, mapreduce, ravendb

I have the following entity collections in RavenDB:

```
public class Provider
{
    public string ProviderId {get; set;}
    public string ProviderName {get; set;}
    public string[] CategoryIds{get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryId {get; set;}
    public string CategoryName {get; set;}
    public string[] ServiceIds {get; set;}
}

public class Service
{
    public string ServiceId {get; set;}
    public string ServiceName {get; set;}
    public string ServiceCode {get; set;}
}
```

This is a 2 level many-to-many relationships. Now I need to create index(es) to flat the structure so i search the results.

1. Search providers that can provider a certain service
2. Search categories that contain a certain service
3. Search services that a provider can provide

My Index result model should like this:

```
public class ProviderCategoryService
{
    public string ProviderId {get; set;}
    public string ProviderName {get; set;}
    public string CategoryId {get; set;}
    public string CategoryName {get; set;}
    public string ServiceId {get; set;}
    public string ServiceName {get; set;}
    public string ServiceCode {get; set;}
}
```

Can I fulfill the above functions just in one index or do i need to create multiple indexes?

**EDIT: use group by multiple field then transformer. **

I come up this index.

```
public class ProviderCategoryServiceSearch:AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<IndexResult>
{
    public ProviderCategoryServiceSearch()
    {
        AddMap<Provider>(providers => from p in providers from c in p.CategoryIds
            select new {
                ProviderId = p.ProviderId,
                ProviderName = p.ProviderName,
                CategoryId = c,           
                CategoryName = (string)null,
                ServiceId = (string)null,
                ServiceName = (string)null,
                ServiceCode = (string)null,
        });

        AddMap<Category>(categories => from c in categories from s in ServiceIds
            select new {
                ProviderId = (string)null,
                ProviderName = (string)null,
                CategoryId = c.CategoryId,           
                CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                ServiceId = s,
                ServiceName = (string)null,
                ServiceCode = (string)null,
        });

        Reduce = results => from r in results
            group r by new {r.CategoryId, r.ServiceId} into g
            from record in g
            select new {
                ProviderId = g.Select(x => x.ProviderId).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                ProviderName = g.Select(x => x.ProviderName).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                CategoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,           
                CategoryName = g.Select(x => x.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                ServiceId = g.Key.ServiceId,
                ServiceName = (string)null,
                ServiceCode = (string)null,
             };
    }


    public class MyTransformer : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<IndexResult>
    {
        public MyTransformer()
        {
             TransformResults = results => from r in results
                 let s= LoadDocument<Service>(r.ServiceId)
                 select new {
                     ProviderId = r.ProviderId,
                    ProviderName = r.ProviderName,
                    CategoryId = r.CategoryId,           
                    CategoryName = r.CategoryName,
                    ServiceId = r.ServiceId,
                    ServiceName = s.ServiceName,
                    ServiceCode = s.ServiceCode,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Any problem with this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

That approach is ok.  It was the way things were done in Raven 1.0 .  However, since the introduction of `LoadDocument` in 2.0 and 2.5, it has become mostly unnecessary.  Read more [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-related-documents).  You will find that you don't need multimap or reduce when you can load a related document into your index map.